# String contains char and return strings Haskell

Tags: haskell

Let's say:

```
let someString = "It is a String"
```

How can I return the words which contain a certain char?

Comment: Regular expressions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could combine `words`, `filter` and `elem` to do that.

Something like this - haven't tested if this exactly works, but it shouldn't be far off:

```
wordsContaining :: String -> Char -> [String]
wordsContaining c = filter (elem c) . words
```

Comment: Can you a bit more specific please? Like a line of code if I can ask? :-)